# How did Tae-Sul and So-Hae end up back on the plane?

Tags: time-travel, sisyphus-the-myth

> I managed to follow every plot point in Sisyphus: The Myth except the part where Tae-Sul and So-Hae are magically alive, the same age, and on a plane together at the end of the last episode. If it had ended there, I could have assumed it was all a dream, but then they show Sigma with everything written down, so that axes that theory. I also briefly thought he was hallucinating So-Hae, because of the pills and the only-one-glass-of-water thing, but that doesn’t explain how he’s alive. (Unless he never made the uploader so nothing ever happened so he never killed himself, and this is the first time around all over again before a brand new loop of loops starts where things change little by little over and over? And So-Hae is just a hallucination the first time? I don’t know that that entirely makes sense either though. Because then none of the things that need to happen to make everyone go back in time will have happened).

What did I miss?

Comment: Since netflix isn't at the end yet, perhaps you should have used the spoiler tag.

Comment: Oh! I didn’t realize it wasn’t over yet!!

Comment: By spoiler tag, we mean this: `>!` You put it before the start of a paragraph, and it hides that paragraph until someone clicks on it.

Comment: @WendiKidd It is over, but people may not have seen the conclusion yet. Some people may not have even started watching it. The spoiler tag (>!) is designed for this.

Comment: There is no indication of future seasons (as yet). I just watched this episode with this question in mind. I am as perplexed as OP.